# Каков порядок загрузки элементов класса?

Tags: java

Есть класс который записывает в сервлет контекст объект DAO слоя.

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private final SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        final DAOImp dao = new DAOImp(new AtomicReference<>(factory));

        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("dao", dao);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Может ли метод `contextInitialized` вызваться раньше чем переменная `factory` получит значение, и почему?

**Update:**
`SessionFactory` это фабрика Hibernate.

Comment: Не может. Переменная будет инициализирована в момент создания объекта.

Comment: А причём тут classloader? И стоит указывать фреймворк.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman указал.

Comment: не знал @WebListener имет отношение к Hibernate